# hot deployment on weblogic 10

Tags: java, weblogic, atg

I'm tired by compiling and redeploying .ear file on web logic. could you please let me know how to do hot deployment. I'm using weblogice 10 as application server and ATG framework. my .ear file is withing ATG not in weblogic. I tried by changing the java file, compiled and merged updated .class file with .jar file and copied .jar file in .ear file but it is not reflected.

Comment: Maybe you copied it into the wrong location...

Answer (score 0):

You should run your server via `runDynamoOnWeblogic.bat` which located in `ATG_DIR\home\bin` and use `-run-in-place` key when call this bat file.
But you should reslove issue with autobuilding in your IDE. For example I config my eclipse so that eclipse compile java classes after editing and put it directly to the `ATG_DIR\My_module\classes.jar` directory.

note: classes.jar should be exploded archive.

Hope this help you.